# Migration error in django, what error am I running into?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, web-applications, pipenv

I am attempting to migrate my changes with command

`python manage.py migrate`

I have already ran the command,

`python manage.py makemigrations accounts`

which successfully returns,

```
Migrations for 'accounts':
  accounts/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model CustomUser
```

Then in attempting to run `python manage.py migrate` I recieve this error...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mycroft/C/news/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/mycroft/C/news/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/mycroft/.local/share/virtualenvs/news-ToLZWqxe/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/mycroft/.local/share/virtualenvs/news-ToLZWqxe/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/mycroft/.local/share/virtualenvs/news-ToLZWqxe/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/mycroft/.local/share/virtualenvs/news-ToLZWqxe/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/mycroft/.local/share/virtualenvs/news-ToLZWqxe/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mycroft/.local/share/virtualenvs/news-ToLZWqxe/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 95, in handle
    executor.loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
  File "/home/mycroft/.local/share/virtualenvs/news-ToLZWqxe/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 302, in check_consistent_history
    raise InconsistentMigrationHistory(
django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency accounts.0001_initial on database 'default'.
```

I am very new to django and can't seem to figure out just what I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you made some changes to you models.py file and these changes aren't sitting well with the inital db structure. If you can track and undo the recent changes it may help, else you'll have to drop your database, delete all migration files your `account` app. Then repeat the makemigration, migrate, and createsuperuser processes.